# C# How can I parse a url to get just the domain name?

Tags: c#, parsing, uri

I want to get the domain name and only the domain name without the TLD
`Before: example.com After: example`

I tried using the package [domainname-parser](https://github.com/danesparza/domainname-parser) but this did not work because my operation is being threaded and I get the error: `The process cannot access the file 'PATH' because it is being used by another process.'` Here:

```
var domaininfo = new DomainParser(new WebTldRuleProvider()).Parse(uri.Host);
```

Comment: Why don't you use a string builder and take the domain name without the TLD?

Comment: because the domains can be different like co.uk etc @TanakaMawere

Comment: This video by https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OjFuBMhJmr4&t=392s&ab_channel=NickChapsas might be of help.

Comment: What result would you expect for `subDomain.myDomain.google`

Answer (score 1):

it's easiest way to use Uri class, but it's not memory efficient.

you should use Span and implement it by yourself if you want memory efficient version.

```
 using System;
 
 public class HelloWorld
 {
     public static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         // you can use Uri class,
         var url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kgTeT3AIM4g";
         var uri = new Uri(url);
         Console.WriteLine(uri.Host); // www.youtube.com
     }
 }
```

Comment: i want to get just "youtube" from that output

Answer (score -1):

Hey man you could try this code:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string urlString = "http://example.site.com/index.html";
        Console.WriteLine(GetDomainNameOfUrlString(urlString));
    }

    private static string GetDomainNameOfUrlString(string urlString)
    {
        var host = new Uri(urlString).Host;
        return host.Substring(host.LastIndexOf('.', host.LastIndexOf('.') - 1) + 1);
    }
```